# What did Newt offer to pay Gnarlack?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In [*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them_(film)) movie, what did Newt offer to pay [Gnarlack](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gnarlak)?

I am not sure what he offered after the coins? I tried googling the answer, but nothing came up.

Comment: A "Lunascope" at least (tool to read easier the moon). For the rest, maybe worth a try to check for subtitles, find the lunascope mention (or "I've got five") and search for the terms around it.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at a script I found online it happened like this.

[image][image]

### So it was money, Lunascope, frozen Ashwinder egg, and then Gnarlak asks for the Bowtruckle.

[script](https://www.pdf-archive.com/2016/11/18/fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-f-j-k-rowling/preview/page/126/)